# TFS build process can't pull nuget package

Tags: tfs, nuget

I've set up a pipeline on TFS 16.131.28601.4. When it gets to the dotnet restore task it tries to pull a package from an internal feed, which is defined in the nuget.config along with the packageSourceCredentials.

The error I get when it fails to pull the package is:

```
Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1...
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://xx.xxx.x.xx:8080/tfs/PVS/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xxx.Api.Client'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
The data is invalid.
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://xx.xxx.x.xx:8080/tfs/PVS/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xxx.Api.Client'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
The data is invalid.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'xxx.Api.Client' from remote source 'http://xx.xxx.x.xx:8080/tfs/PVS/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xxx.Api.Client'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'. [D:\Build\agent\_work\5\s\xxx.Api.Client.Tests\xxx.Api.Client.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   The data is invalid. [D:\Build\agent\_work\5\s\xxx.Api.Client.Tests\xxx.Api.Client.Tests.csproj]
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Failed to retrieve information about 'xxx.Api.Client' from remote source 'http://xx.xxx.x.xx:8080/tfs/PVS/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xxx.Api.Client'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
---> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The data is invalid.
```

The nuget.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear /> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="xxx" value="http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/tfs/PVS/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v2" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <xxx>
      <add key="Username" value="xxxx" />
      <add key="Password" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==" />
    </xxx>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

If I add a nuget restore task it works fine by pulling from the internal feed. Where I get stumped is the "The data is invalid" error, I can't find a reference to it anywhere.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the document about [Use NuGet with Azure DevOps Services feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azure-devops#add-a-feed-to-nuget-2), we can use a 2.x client by replacing /v3/index.json with /v2. But the documentation of [Use dotnet with Azure Artifacts feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/dotnet-exe?view=azure-devops) does not mention that we can do this.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction, once I added the Azure Credentials Provider to my Nuget CI pipeline, it was able to authenticate and restore from the internal feed:

https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider

Also I had to use the v3 endpoint of the nuget feed:

http://xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/tfs/xxx/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json

Comment: I'm glad to know the documents are helpful to you. I summarized your comment in the answer, you can [mark the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and this will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet 4.8.2 and later supports the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider, which automatically acquires feed credentials when needed. We need to use the v3 endpoint of the nuget feed. For example:`xxx.xx.x.xx:8080/tfs/xxx/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json`.
Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azure-devops#add-a-feed-to-nuget-482-or-later).

We can use [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) to authenticate and restore the feeds. The Azure Artifacts Credential Provider automates the acquisition of credentials needed to restore NuGet packages as part of your .NET development workflow.